# Probability of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

How can I compute $P(X>2Y)$ which is exponential distribution. Where $X$ follows exponential distribution with $\lambda = 0.3$ and $Y$ follows exponential distribution with $\lambda = 0.6$.
While X & Y are independent.
Here's where i am stuck at
$=1-P(X<2Y)$
Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: you most probably forgot to mention that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @Vera yes they are independent.. but how 2Y got parameter 0.3 ?

Comment: In general if $Y$ has exponential distribution then so does $aY$ for any positive $a$. This can be deduced for instance by finding the CDF of $aY$. Further $\mathbb E2Y=2\mathbb EY=2/0.6=1/0.3$. That shows that the parameter $\lambda$ is $0.3$ here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint:

If $Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $0.6$ then $2Y$ has exponential distribution with parameter $0.3$ (just like $X$, now apply symmetry).

Comment: what do you mean by Symmetry? I am still confused? Please help.

Comment: If $X$ and $2Y$ have the same distribution and are independent then $P(X<2Y)=P(2Y<X)$. Next to that we have $1=P(X<2Y)+P(X=2Y)+P(2Y<X)$ and if the distributions are continuous also $P(X=2Y)=0$. This leads to $P(X<2Y)=P(2Y=X)=\frac12$.